# How to get Digest authentication right

Tags: c++, authentication, digest, digest-authentication, http-digest

I try to write a C++-application and I have to do HTTP Digest Authentication. The problem is not primarily about C++, but about the fact, that the connection is not being established. The website I try to access is the following: httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd .

Consider the following server response to a simple `GET /digest-auth/auth/user/passwd`:

`HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 08 Sep 2014 15:10:09 GMT
Server: gunicorn/18.0
Set-Cookie: fake=fake_value
Www-Authenticate: Digest realm="me@kennethreitz.com", nonce="2a932bfb1f9a748a7b5ee590d0cf99e0", qop=auth, opaque="2d09668631b42bff8375523e7b27e45e"
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive`

`A1` is then computed to be `user:me@kennethreitz.com:passwd` and is hashed to `4de666b60f91e2444f549243bed5fa4b` which I will refer to as HA1.
`A2` is computed to be `GET:/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd` and hashed to `b44272ea65ee4af7fb26c5dba58f6863` which I will refer to as HA2.

With this information, the response is computed as `HA1:nonce:1:ac3yyj:auth:HA2`, where `HA1` and `HA2` are the values we have just computed and nonce is taken from the server response above, which is in total: `4de666b60f91e2444f549243bed5fa4b:2a932bfb1f9a748a7b5ee590d0cf99e0:1:ac3yyj:auth:b44272ea65ee4af7fb26c5dba58f6863`. The hash of that is `55f292e183ead0810528bb2a13b98e00`.

Combining all that information should be sufficient to establish a http-connection using digest authentication. However, the following request is declined by the server and answered with another `HTTP/1.1 401`.

`GET /digest-auth/auth/user/passwd HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
Authorization: Digest username="user", realm="me@kennethreitz.com",nonce="2a932bfb1f9a748a7b5ee590d0cf99e0",uri="/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd",qop=auth,nc=1,cnonce="ac3yyj",response="55f292e183ead0810528bb2a13b98e00",opaque="2d09668631b42bff8375523e7b27e45e"`

Note that the formatting does not show the structure of the request. The block from Authorization to opaque is actually one line.

Feel free to re-do the md5-calculation  - but I have redone the calculations manually and got the same hashes as my program did. I used that tool (http://md5-hash-online.waraxe.us/) for the manual computations.

Am I missing something obvious here, probably misinterpreting the standard in a way? Why can't I get authorized?

Comment: The RFC gives an example of how it should work. Do you get the same answer?

Comment: @AlanStokes: Hello, that is a good suggestion! I fed my program with the data provided in the RFC example and I got the same hash for `response` as the RFC did. I also sniffed firefox when it connects to httpbin.org and - in my point of view - the request are equal (take a look here: http://pastebin.com/UkpP1shP )... I am really running out of ideas now.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Interesting - looks like curl has the same problem: try `curl -v --digest -u user:passwd http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/user/passwd`

Comment: The correct command is: `curl -v --digest -u user:passwd http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd`

Comment: And lwp-request (`lwp-request -USse -C user:passwd http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd`) is failing, too. I think that the server might be misconfigured - but why can firefox and wget successfully authorize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it. The authentication itself is completely correct.

The server demands a cookie to be set. Apparently one must show that cookie in the reponse, too. That explains why firefox (being a browser) can authenticate correctly while curl and lwp-request can't albeit sticking to the standard - RFC said nothing about cookies. Why do we have standards, that noone cares for?

Anyway, appending `Cookie: fake=fake_value` to the header solves the problem.